# Why search query not showing any result in PHRETS?

Tags: php, rets

I am using this php script to get the result from a simple search query documented [here](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/SearchQuery)

And I have downloaded this excel file of metadata of property [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dvjim401zf318p/rets-metadata-property-1.csv?dl=0)

```
$rets_login_url = "http://sef.rets.interealty.com/Login.asmx/Login";
$rets_username = "xxxxxxxx";
$rets_password = "xxxxxxxx";
$rets_user_agent = "PHRETS/1.0";
$rets_user_agent_password = "xxxxxxx";

//////////////////////////////

// start rets connection
$rets = new phRETS;
// Uncomment and change the following if you're connecting
// to a server that supports a version other than RETS 1.5

$rets->AddHeader("RETS-Version", "RETS/1.5");

$rets->AddHeader("User-Agent", $rets_user_agent);

echo "+ Connecting to {$rets_login_url} as {$rets_username}<br>\n";
$connect = $rets->Connect($rets_login_url, $rets_username, $rets_password, $rets_user_agent_password);

// check for errors
if ($connect) {
        echo "  + Connected<br>\n";
}
else {
        echo "  + Not connected:<br>\n";
        print_r($rets->Error());
        exit;
}

$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","ResidentialProperty","(ListDate=1990-01-01+)");
while ($listing = $rets->FetchRow($search)) {
   echo "Address: {$listing['StreetNumber']} {$listing['StreetName']}, ";
   echo "{$listing['City']}, ";
   echo "{$listing['State']} {$listing['ZipCode']} listed for ";
   echo "\$".number_format($listing['ListPrice'])."\n";
}


$rets->FreeResult($search);

echo "+ Disconnecting<br>\n";
$rets->Disconnect();
```

when I run this script it shows the result connected and then disconnected. But no result is found. I tried many things suggested on some questions for which result was not showing, But nothing is working for me. Where I am wrong?

My RETS server information are here:

RETS Server:    SEF RETS System
RETS System ID: SEFRETS
Login URL:  http://sef.rets.interealty.com:80/Login.asmx/Login
RETS Version:   1.5
Server Software:    Microsoft-IIS/6.0

I also could not understand what is `$rets_modtimestamp_field = "LIST_87";`

Please Help me. I need some suggestion over how to get data from the RETS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the parameters in your SearchQuery.

One of the fields in your search query is ListDate. Looking at the attached excel file containing the metadata, "ListDate" is in Column B under StandardNames. The [RETS specification](http://www.reso.org/assets/RETS/Specifications/rets_1_7_2.pdf) uses System Names as default (see below). You need to specify '"StandardNames" => 1' in the options parameter in the SearchQuery function:

$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","ResidentialProperty","(ListDate=1990-01-01+)",array("StandardNames" => 1));

Also, check to make sure the second argument, class, of your SearchQuery is correct. To do this you could use the [GetMetadataClasses](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetMetadataClasses) function in PHRETS.
You could also use [retsmd.com](http://retsmd.com/) by logging in with your RETS Server url, username, and password.

The $rets_modtimestamp_field is the field which is a datetime value indicating the date and time when a listing was last modified.

---

In section 7.4.7 in the RETS 1.7.2 Specification document, http://www.reso.org/assets/RETS/Specifications/rets_1_7_2.pdf,

"Queries may use either standard names or system names in the query (Section 7.7). If the
client chooses to use standard names, it MUST indicate this using the StandardNames
argument...If this entry is set to ("0") or is not present the field names passed in the search are the
SystemNames, as defined in the metadata."

Comment: but I am not able to search by city name the query is: $query ="(922=MIAMI)" ; in    $search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property", $class, $query, array("StandardNames" => 1, 'Limit' => 10, )); and I have also used $query ="(City=MIAMI)"

Comment: @AndrewBriggs
Looking to have some RETS work done. I live in Vegas as well. If interested, my profile has my contact info. Thanks, Eddie

Answer (score 1):

To address your last comment, you need to specify ListingStatus as well, as it is also a required field when running a query. The lookup values for ListingStatus are:

- A = Active-Available
- B = Backup Contract-Call LA
- C = Cancelled
- CS = Closed Sale
- PS = Pending Sale/Rental
- Q = Terminated
- T = Temp Off Market
- W = Withdrawn
- X = Expired

So try something like this instead:

```
$query ="(922=MIAMI),(246=A)";
```

Or if you're using standard names:

```
$query ="(City=MIAMI),(ListingStatus=A)";
```

And finally:

```
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property", $class, $query, array("StandardNames" => 1, 'Limit' => 10, ));
```

This should allow you to get some results back at least. Beyond that you can just tweak your query until you get the results you want.